# Vim search and replace based on buffer 'coordinates'

Tags: vim

In vim you can select some text visually and then issue a command to act only on the text selected visually, for example search and replace 'foo' with 'bar' in selection `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g`.

The question is, can you do the same without visually selecting the text beforehand? I would like to specify in the command itself the start position and end position for the command, something like `starting line 3 character 6, ending line 5 character 10`

Comment: With `'<,'>` you cannot specify that a substitute starts or ends at a specific character, it works on entire lines.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden but can it done some other way? for example `:1,10s/foo/bar/g` search and replace in lines 1 to 10... can positions on line be added as well?

Answer (score 3):

It is currently unavailable.

Range in Ex Mode is based on lines, as ex is line editor.

This feature has been in Vim's todo.txt too. See here https://vimhelp.org/todo.txt.html, and search for `Substitute in a block of text`

> Substitute in a block of text.  Use {line}.{column} notation in an Ex
> range, e.g.: ":1.3,$.5s" means to substitute from line 1 column 3 to the
> last line column 5.

Comment: Thanks, I found kind of a workaround in the meantime:

`:call cursor(3, 6) | :execute 'normal! v' | :call cursor(5, 10) | :'<,'>s/foo/bar/g`

Comment: @skamsie that’s a great workaround (while a bit long) you’ve found there! I myself just knew about `call cursor(line, column)` now. thanks!